# Two images one left one right and center vertically

Tags: html, css

I have this code, which aligns two images to left and right side of the page with space between:

```css
.center {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.leftk {
  display: table-cell;
}
.rightk {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="leftk">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/300/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="rightk">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/400/100" />
  </div>
</div>
<span>Text</span>
```

I tried to do the same with `inline-block`, but I am unable to align vertically right image to center. Can you please show me a quick example to how to get same result with `inline-block`?

**Edit:** If page size is smaller than image width, I want to display them under each other.

Comment: Why not just keep with table and then use a media query to change the table cell to block when the width is too small?  better than using an inline block hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it with inline block:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs7rcvk2/)**

```css
.center {
  font-size: 0; /*remove white space*/
  text-align: justify;
}
.center:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.leftk,
.rightk {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="leftk">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div class="rightk">
    <img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use css3 **`flexbox`** instead,

- use display:flex instead of display:table
- add justify-content:space-between;

  it's works fine.

```css
.center {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
.leftk>img {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.rightk>img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="leftk" style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rightk">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
<span>Text</span>
```

Comment: It is OK to use flex nowadays? On my site I have IE 9 users around 5-8%.